# How to show a link to related records FROM ALIAS in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have this classes in order to show related records within user and all records on top menu.

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Position, :as => 'Positionsfake' do

belongs_to :user

controller do
 def scoped_collection
   end_of_association_chain.where(category: 1)
 end
end
```

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Position, :as => 'Contactsfake' do

belongs_to :user

controller do
 def scoped_collection
   end_of_association_chain.where(category: 0)
 end
end
```

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Position do

controller do
 def scoped_collection
   end_of_association_chain.where(category: 1)
 end
end
```

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register Position, :as => 'Contacts' do

controller do
 def scoped_collection
   end_of_association_chain.where(category: 0)
 end
end
```

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      User.includes(:provider).where(:providers => {:user_id => nil})
    end
  end

  index do
    column :name
    column "Positions" do |a|
      link_to a.positions.count, admin_user_positions_path(a)
    end
    column "Contatcs" do |a|
      a.contacts.count
  end
  actions
end
```

Positions works fine! But Contacts can`t be called from here.

I have only one model. Contact and Position are the same except in category field. There is any way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of this works for me.

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register User do

controller do
  def scoped_collection
    User.includes(:provider).where(:providers => {:user_id => nil})
  end
end

index do
  column :name
  column :positions do |a|
    link_to a.positions.where(category: 1).count, admin_user_positions_path(a)
  end
  column 'Contacts', :positions do |a|
    a.positions.where(category: 0).count
  end
  actions
end
```

```ruby
ActiveAdmin.register User do

controller do
  def scoped_collection
    User.includes(:provider).where(:providers => {:user_id => nil})
  end
end

index do
  column :name
  column 'Positions' do |a|
    link_to a.positions.where(category: 1).count, admin_user_positions_path(a)
  end
  column 'Contacts', 'Positions' do |a|
    a.positions.where(category: 0).count
  end
  actions
end
```